# Run SQL query from PHP with unique column names?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have ran SQL query PHP lot of times. Usually this is what i do:

```
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);    
$sql = "SELECT AREA,UNIT,COMPLEX,PROPERTY FROM TrimTable";
    $query = sqlsrv_query($con

if ($query === false){  
     echo "Could not link to SQL Server";
}
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query))
{   
      $AREA[] = "$row[AREA]";
      $UNIT[] = "$row[UNIT]";
      $COMPLEX[] = "$row[COMPLEX]";
      $PROPERTY[] = "$row[PROPERTY]";            
}
```

After this i work with my array and manipulate them way i want to. This particular code on top works. But i have few columns in the table that are named unique. One of the column in the table is `LOOP TYPE`. There is also column with `ID#`. I looked online but could find anything. How can i run query on those?

**UPDATE**
This is the code i am trying:

```
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
$sql = "SELECT AREA,UNIT,COMPLEX,`LOOP TYPE` as LOOP, PROPERTY FROM TrimTable";
$query = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);
if ($query === false){  
       echo "Could not link to SQL Server";
}
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query))
{   
    print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: @splash58 That just shows empty page. Doesnt work.

Comment: You should be able to give the column an alias. http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/alias.php The empty page was probably a syntax error did it log anything to your error log?

Comment: run `print_r($row)` to see what the column names are and then use them. Also remove the double quotes - it should be `$row['AREA']` and not `"$row[AREA]"` (after you're changing it - @splash58's comment might be your saviour).

Comment: @uri2x: I get the following error "sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in"

Comment: Make sure you use the same code as above, but place a `print_r($row)` inside the `while` block to see the structure. It cannot affect the `sqlsrv_fetch_array($query)` command in any way.

Comment: @uri2x Check the Update

Answer (score 0):

Use brackets and aliases in the query:

```
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);    
$sql = "SELECT AREA,UNIT,COMPLEX,PROPERTY, [LOOP TYPE] as LOOP, [ID#] as ID FROM TrimTable";
$query = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);

if ($query === false){  
    echo "Could not link to SQL Server";
}
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query))
{   
    $AREA[] = "$row[AREA]";
    $UNIT[] = "$row[UNIT]";
    $COMPLEX[] = "$row[COMPLEX]";
    $PROPERTY[] = "$row[PROPERTY]";      
    $LOOPTYPE[] = "$row[LOOP]";              
    $ID[] = "$row[ID]";    
}
```

Comment: I get the following error: "sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in "

Comment: I think this works. But this is the error i got though: "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8003 bytes) in "

Comment: I think i figure it out. If you do this $LOOPTYPE[] = "$row[LOOP]"; It works. Everything in while loop has to be in that format.

Comment: okay I updated the answer based on your findings. Not sure why "$row[LOOP]" works though.